# React reducer - state not accessible within reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I have the following state/reducer setup:

```
const initialState = {
  inputValues: {
    username: "",
    fullName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  },
  inputValidities: {
    username: false,
    fullName: false,
    email: false,
    password: false
  },
  formIsValid:false
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

I then call dispatch to update the state:

```
dispatch({type: "handleInputChanged", payload: {id, value, validationResult: result}})
```

My reducer looks like so:

```
export function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "handleInputChanged":
            const {id, value, validationResult} = action.payload
            console.log(state.inputValues);

    }
}
```

When attempting to log `state.inputValues`, an error ooccurs stating: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inputValues')**.

How am I able to access the current state input values? Thanks.

Comment: Your reducer doesn't return anything so any subsequent calls will receive an `undefined` state. At the very least, add `return state`

Comment: Maybe add default value to state parameter in reducer. 
`export function reducer (state = initialState, action) { ... }`

Comment: @RasilMaharjan no, that could cause unintended side-effects. Please read the documentation ~ https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer#writing-the-reducer-function

Comment: @Phil but before returning anything, you should be able to see the state values in the log right?

Comment: @RasilMaharjan not if it's been called multiple times, for example by `<StrictMode>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer#usereducer)...

> `reducer`: The reducer function that specifies how the state gets updated. It must be pure, should take the state and action as arguments, and **should return the next state**

Your reducer doesn't return anything which means it returns `undefined`. If your reducer is called multiple times, for example by using `<StrictMode>`, subsequent calls will receive the `state` returned by previous calls.

At the very least, you could return the existing state

```js
export function reducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "handleInputChanged":
      const {id, value, validationResult} = action.payload
      console.log(state.inputValues);
  }

  return state; // or { ...state }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However I'm wondering why the error occurred, because surely `state.inputValues` should equal and log the initial state passed into the reducer ?

Comment: @EesaMunir I thought I made that clear in my answer. Also as an aside, logging from your reducer means it has side-effects and is no longer _pure_. Use your debugger if you want to debug